# dynamicaly change an element if it is changed by a different script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script that modifies the content on a page.  The content is generated from a different script that I am unable to modify.  My code works fine when the page is initially loaded.  But when the user clicks a link (which causes the other script to run) then all my content modifications are lost.  I am able to catch the event that causes the change by using `$(a.pagination_button).on("click",function(){ code })`  But whatever code I put in is not having any effect.  It seems the other script is running after my .on function.  What can I do to make my code execute after the other script so that my changes will be seen by the user?

Comment: You could remove the anchor tags and replace them with exact duplicates after render, thus negating any event bindings. *But*... my real advice is to find a way to not use whatever platform you're using. That isn't a maintainable environment.

Answer (score 1):

Just listen on the document for clicks:

```html
$(document).on("click","a.pagination_button",function() {
   alert("exec code");
});
```